# Redux-toolkit reducer partially changing state

Tags: reactjs, electron, redux-toolkit, immer.js

Hi everyone I have some redux-toolkit issue that I believe comes from immer but cannot be sure.

Using createSlice I am creating reducer to manage open/close/move/add of UI tabs. all of the reducers are working properly except the closeTab reducer.

This is an example of the state at the moment of execution of closeTab reducer:

```
[{
    id: 1,
    active: false,
    tittle: 'Cute',
},
{
    id: 2,
    active: true,
    tittle: 'Cute',
}]
```

This is the entire createSlice

```
export const tabsSlice = createSlice({
    name: "tabs",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        moveTab: (tabs, action: PayloadAction<{ dragIndex: number, hoverIndex: number }>) => {
            tabs.splice(action.payload.hoverIndex, 0, tabs.splice(action.payload.dragIndex, 1)[0]);
        },
        selectTab: (tabs, action: PayloadAction<number>) => {
            tabs.forEach(tab => tab.active = tab.id === action.payload);
        },
        closeTab: (tabs, action: PayloadAction<number>) => {
            const isCurrentActive = tabs[action.payload].active;
            tabs.splice(action.payload, 1);

            if (isCurrentActive && tabs.length !== 0) {
                const newActive = action.payload === 0 ? 0 : action.payload - 1;
                tabs[newActive].active = true;
            }

            if (tabs.length === 0) {
                tabs.push({
                    id: Date.now(),
                    active: true,
                    tittle: 'Cute2'
                })
            }
        },
        addTab: (tabs) => {
            tabs.forEach(tab => tab.active = false)
            tabs.push({
                id: Date.now(),
                active: true,
                tittle: 'Cute2'
            })
        },
    }
})
```

As mentioned `moveTab`, `selectTab` and `addTab` work perfectly but when `closeTab` is executed,
the array is spliced (the tab is removed), but the `active` property of the state is not changed. And I am sure that at the end of the reducer the state is as I want it.

State should be changed from:

```
[{
    id: 1,
    active: false,
    tittle: 'Cute',
},
{
    id: 2,
    active: true,
    tittle: 'Cute',
}]
```

to

```
[{
    id: 1,
    active: true,
    tittle: 'Cute',
}]
```

But in the component I am receiving this:

```
[{
    id: 1,
    active: false,
    tittle: 'Cute',
}]
```

The array length is changed, but not the `active` property

Comment: Are you sure this happens when you try to remove the active tab?

Comment: absolutely yes.

Comment: post your jsx and how you call the action

Answer (score -1):

false issue selectTab overriding closeTab